# stuck on trying connect angular frontend to java backend via port 8080

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to connect the frontend talking to backend via rest api at port 8080, the frontend runing on nginx with very basic config that serve the static content in root folder and proxy the request to api via /api

Below is the config and deployment.

> 1/ backend deployment and service yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wetrust-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wetrust-backend
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: "leean/wetrust-backend"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-volume
              mountPath: /home/uploadDir # Please change the destination you like the share to be mounted too
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-volume
          nfs:
            server: 192.168.99.98 # Please change this to your NFS server
            path: /home/uploadDir # Please change this to the relevant share
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wetrust-backend
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: wetrust-backend
    tier: backend
```

> 2/ frontend deploy and service yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wetrust-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wetrust-frontend
        tier: frontend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: "leean/wetrust-frontend"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wetrust-frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8889
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: wetrust-frontend
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
```

> 3/ nginx config inside the dist folder of static artifacts to build to image

```
upstream wetrust-backend {
  server wetrust-backend:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  charset uft-8
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

  #location / {
   # proxy_pass http://backend;
  #}
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://wetrust-backend;
  }
```

}

I'm now struggling to make the front end talking to the backend by nginx proxy pass as in config , but it no help

after deploy all yaml file without any issue , i can access to the frontedn via the nodeport at service port like 192.168.x.x:30812

the UI worked but failed to connect api at backend port 8080 ( springboot app)

below is the nginx log on the pod hosted frontend

```
 10.244.0.0 - - [01/Sep/2019:05:30:04 +0000] "GET /Simple-Line-Icons.0cb0b9c589c0624c9c78.woff2?v=2.4.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 30064 "http://192.168.99.98:30812/styles.c40c8aff0199546fb524.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
2019/09/01 05:30:09 [error] 7#7: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/authenticate" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.244.0.0, server: localhost, request: "POST /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.98:30812", referrer: "http://192.168.99.98:30812/"
10.244.0.0 - - [01/Sep/2019:05:30:09 +0000] "POST /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://192.168.99.98:30812/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
```

I would appreciate for your help , it took me too much time on this issue
Thank you

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Can you talk to the front-end? Using what port? You didn't specify a nodePort value, so you have to find out which port was allocated for the NodePort first. When you issue calls to that port, do you see any activity in nginx logs? What address is it trying to proxy?

Comment: ah , i can access to the frontend via nodePort at the master node/worker nodes like 192.168.x.x::32115 , the UI of frontend showed up but the authenticate failed since it need to talk to api/authenticate . It get 404 error

the nginx log on the pod running show the error:

Comment: In that case, another thing to check is whether you're proxying to the correct address. The way it is written, iirc, a request with /api/path will be proxied to the backend as http://wetrust-backed:8080/api/path. Is that how the backend is expecting? You can look at the nginx logs to verify this.

Comment: i just update the log on the post, i check the log and see that the issue but i have no idea where the issue coming from nginx proxy pass or the serviceName in yaml file is the issue, Could you take a look on the nginx conf and double check with the yaml declaration ? i'm so new to this and just google for the deployment.

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Looks like your nginx is using its default configuration, not the configuration you posted. It is trying to lookup the /api/authenticate file locally, it is not proxying it.

Comment: so did you see any abnormal with nginx conf i posted ? i did find any error with it

Comment: maybe i missed this important line in dockerfile
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Comment: nginx *should* be using the longest matching uri, in this case, /api/. To make sure you have things configured correctly, maybe you can try removing the location /, leaving only the proxy location and see what it does.

Comment: i checked default nginx config on /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf then it is the default , there is no my custom nginx conf i made because i missed a step of copy my custom config to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf at Dockerfile
Thank you

Comment: add an answer if you resolved the issue

Comment: the issue has been resolved, the reason is i forgot override the custom nginx config to the default config in the dockerfile, then the frontend can not be bridge to the /api with upstream server.
Thank everyone for reading and supporting